# iCloud Key-value storage signin error after changing team ID

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, keychain, provisioning-profile

```
Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.company.appname" doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement.
```

I've changed my application team id and after that it returns above error when using Automatically manage signin when I use Key-value storage option in iCloud.

My application already published on AppStore. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I have the exactly issue after transferring the app store. Did you manage to solve it @isuru?

Comment: @ErickMaeda Actually there's no way to keep Key-value storage when we change Application identifier. So I removed Key-value storage option or else we can use different identifier. However it will remove previous stored Key-value storage related to app.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I think I found a way to solve it. Look at your app's entitlements and you'll see that a key called **iCloud Key-Value Store (com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier)** with the value **$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)**.

You have to replace $(TeamIdentifierPrefix) with your previous team ID (the one you had before transferring). Suppose your previous Team ID was: 4129UNA29J, it should end up looking like: 4129UNA29J.$(CFBundleIdentifier)

Let me know if it helped!